# Writing values of an if statement to file

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have an issue with the if statement, basically I want to write the values of `$tag9700` and `$tag9701` to the `9700l.log` and `9701l.log` respectively if they exist.  If they don't then write `9700=,` to 9700l.log and `9701=,` to `9700l.log`.

```
tag9700=`egrep -Eo '9700=[0-2]{0,9}' $filename-PDK-AP-LXFXMR-01*.log`

if [ $tag9700 -eq 0 ]
then
    echo $tag9700 >> /home/user/9700l.log
else
    echo '9700=,' >> /home/user/9700l.log
fi

tag9701=`egrep -Eo '9701=[A-Z]{0,9}' $filename-PDK-AP-LXFXMR-01*.log`

if [ $tag9701 -eq 0 ]
then
    echo $tag9701 >> /home/user/9701l.log
else
    echo '9701=,' >> /home/user/9701l.log
fi
```

The outcome is that `9700l.log` file should look like:

```
9700=1
9700=0
9700=,(only if it isn't a value grepped in the intial $tag9700)
```

The same scenario applies to `$tag9701`.

Comment: So, what's the issue? Except that you're missing the quotes on `if [ "$tag9700" -eq 0 ]`, and what you probably want is `if [ -n "$tag9700" ]` anyway. I don't think that grep will ever print a zero.

Comment: See e.g. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#A.5B_.24foo_.3D_.22bar.22_.5D and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters (though the latter doesn't touch the test directly)

Answer (score 0):

```
tag9700=`egrep -Eo '9700=[0-2]{1,9}' $filename-PDK-AP-LXFXMR-01*.log`
echo "${tag9700:-,}" > 9700.logfile
```

You need a minimum of `1` match. Then on an unsuccessful match, you make use of the bash substitution property `${var:-...}`

Comment: if [ -z "${tag9700+xxx}" ]
      then
              echo '9700=,' >> /home/user/9700l.log
       else
                echo "$tag9700"  >> /home/user/9700l.log
   fi

Comment: I got it working with that partially but the problem I have is if a 9700 tag isn't present in the logs it doesn't write 9700=, to 9700l.log